# Status of questions in "Group Actions on $\mathbb{R}$-trees"?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Culler and Morgan's "Group Actions on $\mathbb{R}$-trees" lists four questions at the end of the introduction. A few have been famously resolved by work of Rips, Bestvina–Feighn and others.

I'm curious about the status of the remaining questions?

Let me briefly recall:  an $\mathbb{R}$-tree is a metric space where any  two points are connected by a unique arc, which is isometric to a  closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$. An action of a group $G$ on $T$ by isometries without global fixed point yields a *translation length function,* which I will think of as a point in the projective space $P(\mathbb{R}^\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is the set of conjugacy classes of elements of $G$. The set of all such functions is $PLF(G) \subset P(\mathbb{R}^\Omega)$, and the subspace consisting of "small" actions (the precise definition is maybe not relevant to the question) is $SLF(G)$.

Here are the questions.

1. *Is every pseudo-length function a translation length function?*

Culler and Morgan show that translation length functions satisfy certain axioms. The question is whether these axioms completely characterize translation length functions. *Edit:* The axioms characterize $\Lambda$-trees more generally; the paper is ["Axioms for Translation Length Functions"](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=136390&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=30&mx-pid=1105338) by Walter Parry.

2. *Are the simplicial actions dense in $PLF(G)$ or in $SLF(G)$? If so this would give a structure theorem for those groups whose space of conjugacy classes of discrete and faithful representations into $SO(n,1)$ is non-compact. Such groups would decompose non-trivially as free products with amalgamation, or as HNN-extensions, along virtually abelian subgroups.*

My understanding is that both parts of this question are resolved in the affirmative for *stable* actions of *finitely-presented* groups, (which includes actions of discrete subgroups of $SO(n,1)$) due to Rips and Bestvina-Feighn, building on work of Morgan, Shalen, Bestvina and Paulin.

3. *What is the topology of $PLF(G)$ and $SLF(G)$? For example, when are these spaces infinite-dimensional?*
4. *Which finitely-generated groups act freely on $\mathbb{R}$-trees? Peter Shalen asks whether such a group must be a free product of abelian groups and surface groups.*

My understanding is that this is also answered in the affirmative by Rips.

Comment: 2 is open for finitely presented groups and general actions; 4 is proven by Rips.

Comment: In his 1987 article "Dendrology of groups: an introduction", Shalen also attributes 1 to the unpublished preprint "Pseudo-length functions on groups" by W. Parry.  Presumably the Parry in question is Walter Parry, who has published extensively in the area.

Comment: @HJRW Ahh, thanks for the prompting to look at Walter Parry's papers more closely! The paper's title had changed.

Comment: As for 3: Cohen and Lustig prove in "Very small group actions on R-trees and Dehn twist automorphisms" that if $G=A*B$ is a free product of groups such that $B$ contains an element of infinite order, then the subspace of simplicial actions in $SLF(G)$ is infinite dimensional.